# python list controlled increment

Tags: python, list, increment

I'm trying to increment a python list of numbers like an abacus.

```
list = [0,0,0,0]
units = 4

def m(list, units):
  for e in range(len(list)):
    if units:
      list[e] = list[e] + 1
      units -= 1
```

This code works fine in that if I run `m(list, units)` the list will be [1,1,1,1] -- the problem I am trying to solve is that when the units value is something like `units = 2` the list will increment to [2,2,1,1] (which again is fine) the problem is when I run the `m()`function from an uneven list, the list will increment from list[0] to end up [3,3,1,1] rather than [2,2,2,2].

**Is there a pythonic way I can have the function increment the list from the lowest value to achieve an even spread?**

Comment: Do you mean you want to start from `list.index(min(list))` (FYI, `list` is **not** a good name for a list, as it shadows the built-in)?

Comment: Yes, jon - that's exactly it, I'd like to start from the min index -- and I only used the "list" name to make the question easier to read --- thanks -- is there a good way to start from the lowest index of the list?

Comment: Yes, there is - take the snippet I've provided and figure out where to plug it in.

Comment: Ah, perfect Jon -- question answered perfectly -- know exactly where to put it - thank you.

Comment: I'm new - how do I mark this as answered?

Comment: You can't; that's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Pip S: if you're confident your solution is working, you can answer your own question. Tip: you should really not use 'list'. Replace it with something like 'ls'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to begin at the first element with the minimum value, you can set the starting index to `starting_index = abacus.index(min(abacus))` as @jonrsharpe suggests.

However, you need to avoid going beyond the end of the list, for example if `units = 4` and `starting_index = 3`, so you should take the remainder of your calculated index after dividing by `len(abacus)`, i.e. `calculated_index % len(abacus)`.

Finally, I think it would be easier just to loop over `range(units)`. That way you don't need to decrement units yourself, and can handle adding more units at once than the length of the abacus.

Here is an example implementation:

```
def m(abacus, units):
    starting_index = abacus.index(min(abacus))
    for raw_index in range(units):
        index = (raw_index + starting_index) % len(abacus)
        abacus[index] = abacus[index] + 1
```

And test:

```
abacus = [0,0,0,0]    
print abacus
m(abacus, 2)
print abacus
m(abacus, 4)
print abacus
m(abacus, 3)
print abacus
m(abacus, 3)
print abacus
m(abacus, 7)
print abacus
```

With result:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 1, 1]
[3, 2, 2, 2]
[3, 3, 3, 3]
[5, 5, 5, 4]
```

Comment: This solution is so beautiful it nearly made me cry.  Thanks!  Question answered!  -- My solution was a horrible bunch of if else statements to decide when the index started -- your solution is much more verbose and "pythonic" thanks again.

Comment: This line is great: `index = (raw_index + starting_index) % len(abacus)` -- Very elegant statement.  Wonderful.